# Bash, reading data from file

Tags: bash

I have a problem with Bash. I have to create a "simple" program which i reading data from file called "vektor". Data is simple numbers separated with a semicolon(;), for example: (1;2;3;4;5). Then i have to select a operation i want to to. First is a looking for the biggest number of this collection. So, how can I enter the data to the array? or simple variable and make then a selected operation?

I am sorry for my English but I begin learning.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? does it have to be completed natively in `bash` or are other standard tools such as sed/awk/perl allowed? Please provide a more complete example - are the parentheses part of the format as well?

Comment: Yes, its a homework. If I could choose the programming language... dream. Unfortunately I have to use Bash.

Comment: In the first step of my homework I have to read somehow data from file which name i should choose while program is running.

Comment: Second step is choice between counting maximum number of file or counting sum of all number of my collection

Comment: I have to use commands like: select, brake, continue and if or case

Comment: Data in file looks like that:  1;2;3;4;5;6;7  - it's just a simple example. Everything is written is first verse.

Comment: So what **exactly** is your question? `select . . .  case` and the other things you mention relate to *program flow* and have nothing much to do with reading data from a file. What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to read data from file which are separated with semicolon (;).

Comment: And I don't know how to put all of this data to array without semicolon.

Comment: You can set the bash shell's *internal field separator* before reading data. For example `IFS=\; read -a myarray < datafile`

Comment: [This page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263521/how-to-read-and-split-comma-separated-file-in-a-bash-shell-script) seems to have some good advice. I just went to Google and searched for: ubuntu bash read file data into an array semicolon. That version is separating by a colon character but it's not that difficult to make it instead use the semicolon character for your assignment.